# Error separating scores when running quiz multiple times

Tags: python

For my work, I have to run the quiz 3 times and print 3 separate scores. However when I run the code, it runs the quiz 3 times but only prints the final quiz score to python and the text file.

The main part of the code I am currently trying to work on is;

```
NB_QUESTIONS = 2
NB_QUIZNUMBER = 3 

for _ in range(NB_QUIZNUMBER):
    score = 0
    for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
       num1 = random.randint(1,25)
       num2 = random.randint(1,25)
       op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
       print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
       if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
           print("Correct")
           score += 1
       else:
           print("Incorrect")
```

This is the full code just if it is required:

```
import random
import operator

OPERATIONS = [
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]

NB_QUESTIONS = 2
NB_QUIZNUMBER = 3
def get_int_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
      try:
        return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid input (integer is expected)")

def get_bool_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
            return True
        elif val == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            print("Not a valid input (yes/no is expected)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("What is your name?").title()
    class_name = input("Which class do you wish to input results for? ")
    print(name, ", Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test")

    for _ in range(NB_QUIZNUMBER):
        score = 0
        for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
           num1 = random.randint(1,25)
           num2 = random.randint(1,25)
           op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
           print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
           if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
               print("Correct")
               score += 1
           else:
               print("Incorrect")

    print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)

    filename = class_name + ".txt"

    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(name) + " : " + str(score) + '\n')

    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f = open(filename, "r")
        lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
        f.close()
        lines.sort()

    if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
        for line in lines:
            print (line)
    else:
        input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the score for each quiz, you should print it inside the loop - `for _ in range(NB_QUIZNUMBER):` , assuming that is the loop where you iterate for each quiz.

code -

```
for _ in range(NB_QUIZNUMBER):
    score = 0
    for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
       num1 = random.randint(1,25)
       num2 = random.randint(1,25)
       op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
       print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
       if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
           print("Correct")
           score += 1
       else:
           print("Incorrect")
    print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)
```

Comment: This allows the quiz to run 3 times, however it asks the user if it wishes to view the results the first 2 times which I do not want to happen

Comment: What do you mean? You want to print out the score three times right?